# Why leg spin bowler is more expensive then off spin?

Tags: cricket

I see lot of matches and almost every match leg spin bowler is more expensive then off spin bowler but leg spin bowler is more wickets then off spin bowler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general leg spinner tend to be have less control over the ball, so they ball more loose deliveries start of the innings and tend to leak runs. Off spinner have more controller on the ball.

Comment: Can you elaborate why leg spinners have less control over the ball than off spinners.